# Careers 2.0 for Germany

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, careers-germany

First off, apologies if this the incorrect stack exchange for this feedback. I clicked the 'Feedback is Welcome' button on Careers and ended up here, so I assume this is where I should be.

Seeing that Careers was doing a beta for the German version of the site, I went ahead and activated a profile on it. I was glad to see that much of my existing Careers info had already been pre-populated but noticed two things:

1. My City and State were populated incorrectly. I don't recall if I had previously entered a City and State (I updated it when I first saw it was incorrect) but my profile said I was a resident of Postal, Missouri. I believe perhaps that the English -> German translation was incorrectly applied to whatever default values these fields have in the database (perhaps every occurrence of Address was translated to Postal? Ich weiß wirklich nicht)
2. I wrote a brief background statement auf Deutsch for the German version of the site. I had assumed this would be separate from any personal statements on the normal version of my profile but realized with some consternation that my hintergrund was also my background. I propose that the localized version of the Careers pages not necessarily be reflected on your English Careers account; my display of my quite marginal German skills, while surely a useful indicator of my (un?)employability in Germany, is liable to cause a whole lot of WTF?-age for those employers whom I was not targeting with that text.

Danke für deine Zeit :)

Comment: Postal, Missouri? So *that's* where "Going Postal" comes from.

Comment: What exactly did you put into the city and state field? Were you on the german or english site when you did it?

Comment: @mjibson I changed it to Columbia, SC on the German version of the site. Postal, MO was prepopulated on the German version of the site when I first activated the account. I don't believe I had previously provided a city and a state on my English profile but I may be mistaken on that.

Comment: @IamChuckB The German and English sites have the same data. You have just one account/profile, but multiple ways to see it.

Comment: @mjibson that explains bullet point #2 but I do still wonder where Postal, MO came from because I'm certain I didn't enter that anywhere, at any time. Also, if there's only the one profile underlying it all, then I'd like to make a feature request for the ability to have some locale specific entry fields that are only activated when you sign up for a localized version of Careers. I think this would be useful for the reasons I outlined in the original question. It could be similar to how we can have different 
"About Me" sections on different sites within stack exchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took us a while, but we finally figured out where "Postal, Missouri" was coming from. Some form fields on the profile page contain a placeholder such as "street", "city":

[image]

It looks like your browser sent the placeholder text "zip/postal" as actual form input. On geocoding your location on our side, "Postal, Missouri" then was returned as a match and your city and state information got updated accordingly.

<s>It's not clear why the placeholder value got sent as actual input text, we will investigate this further. But, at least</s> The placeholder values got submitted due to a glitch in older browsers. We implemented a fix for this, so it shouldn't happen anymore. And the mystery of [Postal, Missouri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal,_Missouri) is now solved...

Comment: If you're using polyfills for the placeholders I'd look at that. I don't believe html5 placeholders can ever be "submitted" as data

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. This only affects older browsers.

Comment: A fix in now in place, so this shouldn't happen anymore in any browser. Problem was that modifying form fields on submission requires cancel & new submit, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7059589.